# Best Practice for Design A Identifier AST in Rust

Tags: parsing, rust, abstract-syntax-tree

I am learning Rust and implementing a toy parser, At the beginning I definite my AST like

```rust
struct ASTIdentifier {
   name: String,
}
```

the problem with this design is that I need to allocate heap space for each identifier, and each identifier's name should come from the source code, which means it does not need extra memory space. So  I change my struct to use &str.

```
struct ASTIdentifier <'source_code_lifetime> {
    name: &'source_code_lifetime str,
}
```

This struct indeed improves my parser performance, because it does not need to allocate memory space for identifiers.
But there comes a new problem, how do I transform the Identifier name? because now it is using a reference to str.

Comment: I've done hybrids in the past where the AST node referenced the source buffer until its value needed transformation at which point the string was copied to a local member. This requires more conditional logic throughout, of course, but was still well worth the added complexity in terms of performance because transformations were comparatively rare in my case.

Comment: If you have a second question, ask another question rather than invalidating an answer to your first question. You can even link to this question in that one and indicate it is a follow-up question.

Answer (score 2):

You're describing the exact raison d'être of [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html).

```rust
struct AstIdentifier<'source_code> {
    name: Cow<'source_code, str>
}
```

to initially store a `&str` in there:

```rust
impl AstIdentifier<'_> {
    fn new(name: &str) -> Self {
        Self { name: name.into() }
    }
}
```

and you can use `to_mut` to convert to a `Cow::Owned` if it isn't already and return a mutable reference to the string:

```rust
ast_identifier.name.to_mut().push_str("_some_more");
```

Comment: HI @cafce25 thanks for answering my problem, it is indeed increasing the performance. but I have another problem. How to generate code from Cow type, I try using a string as output and call `as_ref` for every ast node, but the performance of this method is pretty bad.